# Pass Variable to Amazon Redshift?

Tags: powerbi

I am new to using Amazon Redshift. I'm tasked with writing queries for our executive office.  However, I need to pass a variable into these queries, based on user input. For example, I want to know what the results are for October 2023, but may want to know the results for September next time I run the query. The results will be collected into a report using Microsoft PowerBI, which is our main corporate tool. In the past, I'd use Microsoft SQL Server. I would normally create stored procedures and pass variables into the stored procs from the application.

Question - I'm not able to find anything from searching. I want to pass a variable to the redshift database query so that I can get the results based on user input.

How do I do this?

So, here's what I'm looking for.  My name is Kai.  If I want to to find results based on my name, I'd pass that as a variable.

SELECT
id,
account_id,
other_information

FROM
myTable
WHERE
first_name='KAI'

So, how do I pass "Kai" into the query from PowerBI?